# Problem with generics and interfaces and inheritance

Tags: delphi, generics, interface

The following example is giving me this error:
`[DCC Error] Unit2.pas(54): E2010 Incompatible types: 'IBar' and 'Unit2.TFoo<Unit2.IBar>'`

I think the problem is somewhere around the Self.Create
Because after many tries to get it compiled I accidentally entered FFoo := TBar(Self).Create; and it compiled and worked.

I'm using Delphi XE

```
IFoo = interface
end;

TFoo<T: IInterface> = class(TInterfacedObject, IFoo)
private class var
  FFoo: T;
public class
  function Instance: T;
end;

IBar = interface(IFoo)
end;

TBar = class(TFoo<IBar>, IBar)
end;

class function TFoo<T>.Instance: T;
begin
  if not Assigned(FFoo) then
  begin
    FFoo := Self.Create;
  end;
  Result := FFoo;
end;
```

Comment: The error tells you a line number. Perhaps you could point out exactly what line that is instead of guessing where the problem might be?

Comment: The error is on the line after "end."

Comment: The cast `TBar(Self).Create` is unwanted as you are not sure that Self is a TBar **and** it will break the concept of generics (not usable for another class)!

Comment: It is really a shame what line numbering is not supported here.

Comment: Still the same in 2017 and Tokyo.2

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in this line with the TBar declaration:

```
FFoo := Self.Create;
```

To understand, let's explain the types behind the code [noted like this]:

```
FFoo:[IBar] := Self:[TFoo(IBar)].Create():[TFoo<IBar>]
```

So, tu summarize, we have : `[IBar] := [TFoo<IBar>]`
Are these types compatible ?
A **[TFoo]** only implements **IFoo** interface, no **IBar** as it is stated in your code

```
TFoo<T: IInterface> = class(TInterfacedObject, IFoo)
```

This is the compilation error !
**UPDATE : Solution 1**
To fix the issue : change the **TBar** declaration

```
TBar = class(TFoo<IFoo>, IBar)
end;
```

**UPDATE : Solution 2**
Replace the `FFoo := Self.Create` by

```
FFoo := Self.Create.Instance;
```

and so it works !

Comment: That's not the solution because the result type of the function Instance will be IFoo and not IBar.

Comment: @RjK: I've updated my post with **Solution 2**. I think this is what were searching !

Comment: UPDATE : Solution 2 -> This will cause a stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Your TFoo does not implement T as interface. That's why FFoo and an instance of TFoo is not compatible. If you want to assign an instance of TFoo to FFoo you need to hardcast it.

Comment: Do you mean this in the function Instance : Result := T(FFoo); It compiles but when I run it I get an AV on the last end of the function. (Access violation at address 00000001. Read of address 00000001.)